While executing a project in Pycharm using Langchain_Community edition, I am facing the below mentioned error, how to solve this?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tony\conversionProject\conversionProject\.venv\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_community'

I have tried installing the 'langchain-community' module using the pip command, even after doing that I am facing the same error.
